# Stretch and skew planes between posts or points on a bezier curve with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I am trying to stretch and skew a series of planes between cube posts on a bezier curve The bezier curve is set to vector to give only straight lines, but in all possible directions.

The plane will need to follow the posts in all directions (xyz) as the bezier curve points are moved or created

I have only been using geometry nodes for a few weeks and I am using Blender 3.4.1

[image]

Comment: You should update to the [current version](https://www.blender.org/download/).

Comment: Please be so kind and give feedback if the answer below could help you. If not, please be so kind and share where exactly you need help or what should work differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also, as long as we're only dealing with simple cubic shapes here, use the following setup and build everything with *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

Here I just convert the curve into a mesh and extrude the edges upwards. Then I split the faces and scale them. First I scale them on the axis that is perpendicular to the normal of the face, and then on the $Z$-axis. This way I get the fence (at least I assume that your example is a fence, because nobody wants to build a wall).

The posts in this example are also instances of a cube created with *Geometry Nodes*, which I instantiate to the points of the curve and rotate according to the curve points and scale to the desired height.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much